# from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials : cannot import name 'opentype'

Tags: python, google-api, oauth2client

I use python 3.6.0.
I want to play with the Google Drive API.
When I `import oauth2client.service_account` I get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    from oauth2client.service_account import _ServiceAccountCredentials
  File "C:\Users\aaron\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\service_account.py", line 26, in <module>
    from oauth2client import crypt
  File "C:\Users\aaron\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\crypt.py", line 23, in <module>
    from oauth2client import _pure_python_crypt
  File "C:\Users\aaron\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\_pure_python_crypt.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pyasn1_modules.rfc2459 import Certificate
  File "C:\Users\aaron\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyasn1_modules\rfc2459.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pyasn1.type import opentype
ImportError: cannot import name 'opentype'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider upgrading your google-auth module

```
pip install --upgrade google-auth-oauthlib
```

and also the pyasn1_module, which is reponsible for implementation of ASN.1 types and codecs as a Python package

```
pip install --upgrade pyasn1-modules
```

**UPDATE**
Working solution:
Force install your modules

```
pip install -U -I pyasn1 pyasn1-modules
```

Comment: Here is my packages versions :
google-auth-oauthlib=0.2.0
pyasn1-modules=0.2.2

Comment: @AaronAbenDanan: Can you run this pip install -U pyasn1 pyasn1-modules, what i reckon is that there is some other version confliting with your latest pyasn1-modules

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's what I get after the `pip install -U ...` :
`Requirement already up-to-date: pyasn1-modules in c:\users\aaron\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (0.2.2)
Installing collected packages: pyasn1
  Found existing installation: pyasn1 0.1.9
Cannot uninstall 'pyasn1'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.`

Comment: So here you got 2 versions of pyasn1 one is 0.1.9 and other 0.2.2. I suggest you to uninstall pyasn1 completely  "pip uninstall pyasn1-modules==0.1.9" and "pip uninstall pyasn1-modules==0.2.2"....and use pip install -U pyasn1 pyasn1-modules.

Comment: It doesn't work either... I get that :
`Collecting pyasn1-modules
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/19/02/fa63f7ba30a0d7b925ca29d034510fc1ffde53264b71b4155022ddf3ab5d/pyasn1_modules-0.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pyasn1, pyasn1-modules
  Found existing installation: pyasn1 0.1.9
Cannot uninstall 'pyasn1'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.`

Comment: Better force install your modules "pip install -U -I pyasn1 pyasn1-modules"

Comment: Thanks ! It works now