# ImportError: cannot import name 'ServiceAccountCredentials' from 'oauth2client.service_account'

Tags: python

I'm trying to follow along a [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py) on pulling in Google Analytics data using Python.

Having followed the steps throughout the tutorial, when I call the script I get the error message in the title:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredential
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "ga.py", line 4, in 
>       from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
>   ImportError: cannot import name 'ServiceAccountCredentials' from 'oauth2client.service_account'

I was reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52163971/from-oauth2client-service-account-import-serviceaccountcredentials-cannot-impo) SO post after some Googling.

I tried changing my package version:

```
pip install oauth2client==1.5.2
```

I tried adding new packages per the answers on that post:

```
pip install pyopenssl
pip install pycrypto
pip install httplib2
pip install oauth2client
pip install ssl
```

In each case I encountered the same message after trying to run `ga.py`:

> (zen_ga) Macs-MacBook:zen_ga macuser$ python ga.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "ga.py", line 4, in 
>       from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
>   ImportError: cannot import name 'ServiceAccountCredentials' from 'oauth2client.service_account'

How can I import `ServiceAccountCredentials` from `oauth2client.service_account`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, the class you are trying to import is called `ServiceAccountCredentials`, not `ServiceAccountCredential`. So try this instead: `from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials`.

oauth2client 1.5.2 does not include `ServiceAccountCredentials`. Use a more recent version to use it - the latest version is 4.1.3.

Finally, you should note that [oauth2client is deprecated](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2client-deprecation.html), and it is now recommended to use [google-auth](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) instead.

Comment: installing `oauth2client==4.1.3` fixed this for me.

Comment: I installed google-auth only and it did not work... So I have to install oauth2client and it works right away.

Answer (score 0):

My 2cents:

For this to work I had to install and update these packages either

-from WITHIN the NORMAL TERMINAL with PLAIN PYTHON, no distribution such as Conda(dont forget to set Path-Variable):

```
py -m pip install google-api-python-client
py -m pip install oauth2client
```

-or from WITHIN the CONDA TERMINAL with:

```
pip install google-api-python-client oauth2client
pip install --upgrade oauth2client  #important
```

this did NOT WORK when I tried to install and update from jupyter notebook with pip

Answer (score 0):

It works if you import the module alone and then call the class in your code.

Change the import line to:
`from oauth2client import service_account`

and call the class with the module prefixed like so:
`service_account.ServiceAccountCredentials()`